# Python create functions / classes with variables at don't need to be passed in and have default values

Tags: python

I often use **kwargs when I am creating a function, and then (in the event the user does not pass in a variable) I set a default value with a try and except statement like this:

```
def function(**kwargs):

    # Set a default value for 'start_date' if no value passed into the function
    try: start_date = kwargs['start_date']
    except KeyError: start_date = '2022-01-01'
```

I am pretty convinced this is not best practice.  For example when using Pandas DataFrames if a variable is not specified a default value is used.

Eg:

```
df.drop(['column_a'], inplace=True)
```

If 'inplace' is not specified it defaults to False.  How can i reproduce this?

Comment: what is wrong with ths? Aside from the bad-style of not indenting your `try - except`? This is fine. Perhaps you could use `kwargs.get` since `kwargs` is a dictionary, and you can do `self.whatever = kwargs.get("whatever", default_whatever)`, but this is pretty much equivalent logically. Of course, this is assuming you need to use `**kwargs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `**kwargs` you can provide default arguments, which is what they are intended for, which will allow optional parameters

```
def function(start_date='2022-01-01'):
    print(start_date)

>>> function('2022-04-19')  # arg
2022-04-19
>>> function(start_date='2022-02-04')  # kwarg
2022-02-04
>>> function()  # default value
2022-01-01
```

with the other advantage being implicit validation of arguments which `**kwargs` would otherwise happily accept

```
>>> function(wrong=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wrong'
```

Comment: To completely match the old behavior you could also choose to force using kwargs as the only way to override the default. `def function(*, start_date='2022-01-01')`